# Set git user as already existing user in a project

Tags: git

I'm working on a project in a company and I have a git user in my PC there. Now while I'm working remotely and I have cloned the project I want to set my user in my laptop as the same git user but I don't know how. Will having same email address and name in my laptop do the job?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will. If you specify the same name and email in your `.gitconfig`, while working on the same project, there will be no difference between working from your company or working remote.

You can both have a general user, found in `$HOME/.gitconfig`, or per project user, found in your project, under `.git/config`.

Answer (score 1):

In each computer, you should:

```
git config --global user.name "<username>"
git config --global user.email <mail>
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

With the same data.